# Creating a new RAID1 array more quickly

Tags: linux, raid, configuration

I'm new to RAID. Creating a new RAID1 array from blank, newly-partitioned 100GB disks with

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/xvdf1 /dev/xvdg1
```

...looks to be taking about an hour to rebuild. My questions are:

1. are there any shortcuts that can be taken on this initial "resync",
   since there's not   (AFAIK) any data I need copied between the empty
   disks
2. can I blithely format `/dev/md0` and treat it like a normal disk while it's in the middle of its initial sync, as long as I'm okay with it being in a "degraded" state for a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mdadm --create --assume-clean ...
```

See the mdadm manpage for drawbacks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about a shortcut, but you can start to use it immediately, with a reduced performance as only drawback.